# WPForms Lite error: Uncaught RuntimeException: Extraction failed: variable names are clashing with the existing ones

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins

WPForms Lite has caused a fatal error on my WordPress page, and I struggle with figuring out what the problem is and how to fix it.

Error Details:

```
An error of type E_ERROR was caused in line 106 of the file /home/pagename/public_html/wp-content/plugins/wpforms-lite/src/Helpers/Templates.php. Error message: Uncaught RuntimeException: Extraction failed: variable names are clashing with the existing ones. in /home/pagename/public_html/wp-content/plugins/wpforms-lite/src/Helpers/Templates.php:106
```

It seems like the function is supposed to include a template, and the error exists to "protect the scope from modification".

```
Stack trace:
#0 /home/pagename/public_html/wp-content/plugins/wpforms-lite/src/Helpers/Templates.php(127): WPForms\Helpers\Templates::include_html('education/admin...', Array, true)
#1 /home/pagename/public_html/wp-content/plugins/wpforms-lite/includes/functions.php(2402): WPForms\Helpers\Templates::get_html('education/admin...', Array, true)
#2 /home/pagename/public_html/wp-content/plugins/wpforms-lite/src/Lite/Admin/Education/Admin/NoticeBar.php(69): wpforms_render('education/admin...', Array, true)
#3 /home/pagename/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(303): WPForms\Lite\Admin\Education\Admin\NoticeBar->display('')
#4 /home/pagename/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(327): WP_Hook->apply_filters('', Array)
#5 /home/vpagename/public_html/wp-includes/plugin.php(470): WP_Hook->do_action(Arra
```

Comment: Yeah, looks like this simply tries to ensure that none of the template variables provided by the plugin, overwrite any already existing ones. No details here on how you are actually using it, or what context this occurs in, but I guess you probably have to change parameter names used in the configuration or call of the functionality in some place.

Comment: I'm using it for a very basic contact form, and it has been up and running without any issues for about two months now. I used a basic contact form template provided by the plugin itself, and the only customization is a css class and a button color change on my child theme as per WPForms' instructions. I tried disabling the css modification and that did nothing, and there are no other outside factors influencing the plugin.